# What does $this actually mean> Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Silly question I know,

From all the tutorials they do not explain why they use $this.

Is $this like an object from a base class in Codeigniter?

Any explanation would be welcomed! :)

Thanks

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php for an introduction on `$this` itself.

Answer (score 20):

To actually **answer** your question, `$this` actually represents the singleton Codeigniter instance (which is actually the controller object).

For example when you load libraries/models, you're attaching them to this instance so you can reference them as a property of this instance.

Another way to get this instance in codeigniter is the `get_instance()` function that you use when building portable libraries.

Answer (score 7):

`$this` in PHP is the current object. In a class definition, you use `$this` to work with the current object. Take this class as an example:

```
class Hello {
  public $data = 'hello';
  function hi() {
    $this->data = 'hi';
  }
}
```

You can instantiate this class multiple times, but `$data` will only be changed to `hi` in those objects where you called the function:

```
$one = new Hello;
$two = new Hello;
$two->hi();

echo $one->data, "\n", $two->data;
```

Comment: Sure this is a fine tutorial on the generic meaning of `$this` but does not address codeigniter specifically, which is what the question is about.

Answer (score 6):

`$this` isn't something from CodeIgniter, but from PHP. `$this` refers to the current object.

Whenever you create an instance like this:

```
$something = new SomeClass();
```

Then `$this` refers to the instance that is created from `SomeClass`, in this case `$something`. Whenever you are in the class itself, you can use `$this` to refer to this instance.
So:

```
class SomeClass {

  public $stuff = 'Some stuff';

  public function doStuff()
  {
    $this->stuff;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, so basically its similar to C++ in the sense that this.stuff()

Comment: I have no experience with C++, but yes, it probably implements `this` in the same way.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of codeigniter:
You'll notice that each controller in codeigniter extends the base controller class.  Using `$this` in a controller gives you access to everything which is defined in your controller, as well as what's inherited from the base controller.

Most of the use you'll get out of `$this` involves calling methods which the base class has loaded for you - `$this->load`, `$this->uri`, etc.

If I remember correctly, PHP code in a view is run in the context of the controller, so you'll have access to the controller object with `$this` from there as well.

Comment: what if we dont write `$this` will it work in PHP??? As its work in C++ ?? we can write  any data member with `this` or without `this` as well in C++ can we do in PHP????

Comment: @BilalMaqsood - no, PHP does not support that syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I just read a great post about $this and classes in general: http://query7.com/using-this-in-php

> In PHP, the keyword “$this” is used as a self reference of a class and
>   you can use it for calling and using these properties and methods as
>   shown in the example bellow.

Answer (score 1):

It is the way to reference an instance of a class from within itself, the same as many other object oriented languages. From the PHP docs: The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. ... $this is mainly used to refer properties of a class

Answer (score 0):

`$this` used to get/load things like helpers, libraries, database, global variables in your extended class.

For example

```
 $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
 $this->load->library('form_validation');
 $this->load->library("pagination");
```