# What is variable stand-alone $this means in a method in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, this

I am confused about what does the stand-alone variable `$this` actually means in some CodeIgniter functions. I understand `$this` with the arrow, but I don't know how to use `$this` in a function. For example,

```
function update_entry()
{
    $this->title   = $_POST['title'];
    $this->content = $_POST['content'];
    $this->date    = time();

    $this->db->update('entries', $this, array('id' => $_POST['id']));
}
```

Comment: Check out this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181192/what-does-this-actually-mean-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Literally, you **can't use `$this` inside a function**.

`$this` is a **pseudo variable** that refer to *this* object, or rather to a class instance.

You can use it **inside a method,** not inside a function.

Your misunderstanding, however, is totally legitimate, because in php methods are declared through... `function` keyword! The only syntax difference is that a “function” inside a class is a method, whereas a function outside a class is... a function.

Example:

```
<?php
    class MyClass
    {
        public $var = 'Hello';

        /* echo() is a MyClass method */
        function echo()
        {
            echo $this->var;                     // <-- $this inside class: valid
        }
    }

    echo $this;                                  // <-- $this outside class: NOT valid

    /* test() is a function */
    function test()
    {
        echo $this;                              // <-- $this inside function: NOT valid
    }
?>
```

`$this` refer to an instance of the class, so, in this example:

```
$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->test();                                    // <-- Output: "Hello"
$obj->var = "Hello World";
$obj->test();                                    // <-- Output: "Hello World"

$obj2 = new MyClass();
$obj2->test();                                   // <-- Output: "Hello"
$obj2->var = "Hello Baby";
$obj2->test();                                   // <-- Output: "Hello Baby"
```

`$this` is a reference to object `$obj` or `$obj2`, not to the generic declared class: to refer to the current class instead of object you have to use `self` instead of `$this`.

In other words, you have to use `$this` for non-static members and `self` for static members.

---

- See more about [Basic class syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

---

#### Edit:

You remain confused *when "$this" stand alone in a method.*

See this example:

```
class Called
{
    public $var = 'Hello Baltimora';

    function echo( $obj )
    {
        echo $obj->var;
    }
}

class Caller
{
    public $var = 'Hello San Francisco';

    function echo( $obj )
    {
        $obj->echo( $this );
    }    
}

$called = new Called();
$caller = new Caller();

$caller->echo( $called );
```

In the class `Caller`, method `echo` pass `$this` (reference to own instance) to a different class method ( `Called->echo`, instantiated as `$called` ): inside called method, the `Caller` instance (`$caller`) is assigned to `$obj` variable and use to retrieve his `$var` variable.

So, `$caller->echo( $called )` will output “Hello San Francisco”.

Comment: thank you for your correction, but I find "$this" more complicated when I use it in Codeigniter than OOP!! Do you think so??

Comment: It is the same. It is an object instance of Codeigniter (a singleton instance)

Comment: I mean I get confused when "$this" stand alone in a method? specifically in the example in the question above

Comment: I don't know internal CodeIgniter structure, but I think that `->db->update` use it to refer to correct object: i.e. `function update( $entries, $obj, $array ) { $obj->doSomething(); }` inside this method, `$obj` refer to Codeigniter Controller (or to the object parent of method in your example, if it is not the controller). Let me know if I was clear.

Comment: @M.Chandler see edited answer with an additional example