# What is the purpose of using $this in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a quick question:  What is the difference between:

```
    $this->data['page_detail'] = $this->page_model->find_ID();
```

and

```
    data['page_detail'] = $this->page_model->find_ID();
```

?

To add more detail:

```
if ($this->uri->segment(1)=='profile')
        {
            if ( ! $this->data['page_detail'] = $this->page_model->find_alias($this->uri->segment(1)))
                redirect();
```

Why not?

```
if ($this->uri->segment(1)=='profile')
        {
            if ( data['page_detail'] = $this->page_model->find_alias($this->uri->segment(1)))
                redirect();
```

Comment: Your question title and your question text differ. I do however think that this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181192/what-does-this-actually-mean-codeigniter. TL;DR; This is a PHP-Identifier referencing to your current instance. In codeigniter, this is your current container. You can use $this for a more explicit access to variables in case that name shadowing as occurred. To answer your question text (rather than title), there is only syntactic and no semantic difference in the example you've given.

Answer (score 0):

because `$this` represents the singleton Codeigniter instance 
when we load models, we are attaching them to `$this` instance so we can reference them as a property of this instance.
and you also missing `$` sign with `data['page_detail']` it should be like this `$data['page_detail']`

Comment: What does this means: $this->data['page_detail'] ?  I still do not quite understand

Comment: $this->data['page_detail']  don't make any sense data['page_title'] look like key of any data array.  $this is an instance use to select any object within class.  suppose you have 3 function A, B, C if you want to access function C in function A. should be like this .   $this->C();

Answer (score 0):

You want to use it as

```
$data['page_detail'] = $this->page_model->find_ID();
```

It is a variable

Comment: I understand that one.  Okay please cek the code below.  (another post).  My friend code this and the code works well I just cannot read it.  Therefore I post it here, who knows if someone can translate it for me.