# Unable to fetch data in Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

developing quiz in Codeigniter PHP, unable to fetch data its's showing like this, its the field name "quizID" , "question" for every question displaying like this

'quizID'?>.'question'?>

Quiz Model File Code

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class quizmodel extends CI_Model {

public function getQuestions()
{
    $this->db->select("quizID, question, choice1, choice2, choice3, 
answer");
    $this->db->from("QuizQuestion");

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();

    $num_data_returned = $query->num_rows;

    if ($num_data_returned < 1) {
      echo "There is no data in the database";
      exit();   
    }
}
}
```

Question File Code

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Questions extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}

public function quizdisplay()
{
    $this->load->model('quizmodel');
    $this->data['questions'] = $this->quizmodel->getQuestions();
    $this->load->view('play_quiz', $this->data);
 }

    public function resultdisplay()
 {
    $this->data['checks'] = array(
         'ques1' => $this->input->post('quizid1'),
         'ques2' => $this->input->post('quizid2'),
         'ques3' => $this->input->post('quizid3'),
         'ques4' => $this->input->post('quizid4'),
         'ques5' => $this->input->post('quizid5'),
         'ques6' => $this->input->post('quizid6'),
         'ques7' => $this->input->post('quizid7'),
         'ques8' => $this->input->post('quizid8'),
         'ques9' => $this->input->post('quizid9'),
         'ques10' => $this->input->post('quizid10'),
    );

    $this->load->model('quizmodel');
    $this->data['results'] = $this->quizmodel->getQuestions();
    $this->load->view('result_display', $this->data);
}
}
```

Play Quiz File Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Play Quiz</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<h1>Play the Quiz!</h1>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?
>index.php/Questions/resultdisplay">


<?php foreach($questions as $row) { ?>

<?php $ans_array = array($row->choice1, $row->choice2, $row->choice3, $row-
>answer);
shuffle($ans_array); ?>

<p><?=$row->quizID?>.<?=$row->question?></p>

<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[0]?
>" required> <?=$ans_array[0]?><br>
<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[1]?
>"> <?=$ans_array[1]?><br>
<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[2]?
>"> <?=$ans_array[2]?><br>
<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[3]?
>"> <?=$ans_array[3]?><br>

<?php } ?>

<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit!">

</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the controller has an error:

instead of `$this->data['questions'] = $this->quizmodel->getQuestions();`

it should say `data['questions'] = $this->quizmodel->getQuestions();`

same goes for: `$this->data['results'] = $this->quizmodel->getQuestions();`

which should be: data['results'] = `$this->quizmodel->getQuestions();`

`$this` is a singleton Codeigniter instance, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181932/2275490):

The model has also an error, class declaration must be uppercase, read more [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model)

```
class Quizmodel extends CI_Model
```

you may also note, that in the model after `return $query->result();` the remaining code is unreachable, you may want to change it like so:

```
$num_data_returned = $query->num_rows();

if ($num_data_returned < 1) {
  echo "There is no data in the database";
  exit();   
}else{
   return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: showing error Cannot modify header information **data['questions'] = $this->quizmodel->getQuestions();**  int his line and Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Comment: see my edit: Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase. Make sure your class extends the base Model class.

Answer (score 0):

change your model like this and try

```
class quizmodel extends CI_Model {

    public function getQuestions()
    {
        $this->db->select("quizID, question, choice1, choice2, choice3, 
    answer");
        $this->db->from("QuizQuestion");

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $result = $query->result_array();

        $num_data = $query->num_rows();

         if ($num_data ==0) {
           return false;  
         }else{
           return $result;
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: showing error on this file now  **<?php $ans_array = array($row->choice1, $row->choice2, $row->choice3, $row->answer);** in another file of playquiz.php file  and in model file this error **$this->load->view('play_quiz', $this->data);**

Answer (score 0):

class quizmodel extends CI_Model {

```
public function getQuestions()
{
    $this->db->select("quizID, question, choice1, choice2, choice3, 
answer");
    $this->db->from("QuizQuestion");

    $num_data =  $this->db->get()->num_rows();

     if ($num_data == 0) {
       return false;  
     }else{
       return true;
     }
   }
}
```